# Rotating banners with URL links and no duplicates

Tags: javascript, random, rotation, banner

unfortunately I have very little experience with JS so please be patient :p

I am trying to rotate banners on a site. I want to be able to put banners in different locations and have no duplicates shown. It would also be great if the banners were in an array so adding more to the rotation would be simple.

Here is a code I've been trying to get working but have had little success. It has been saved to in rotate.js through notepad

```
script type="text/javascript">


link = new Array
image = new Array

link[1]="www.audio-philia.co.uk"
image[1]="www.hificornershop.co.uk/nodups/audiophilia.gif"

link[2]="www.emporiumhifi.com"
image[2]="www.hificornershop.co.uk/nodups/emporiumhifi.gif"

link[3]=""
image[3]=""

link[4]=""
image[4]=""

link[5]=""
image[5]=""

link[6]=""
image[6]=""

link[7]=""
image[7]=""

link[8]=""
image[8]=""

link[9]=""
image[9]=""

link[10]=""
image[10]=""


rnd = (Math.round((Math.random()*9)+1))

document.write('<a href="' + link[rnd] + '" target="_blank">'); 
document.write('<img src="' + image[rnd] + '" border="0"></a>');

value = array.splice(rnd,1)[0]; // remove the selected number from the array and get it in another variable

logosElement.innerHTML += (value);
}

</script>
```

I would then copy the following into the areas I want the banners displayed#

`<img src='rotate.js?i=0'>image #1 
<img src='rotate.js?i=1'>image #2 
<img src='rotate.js?i=2'>image #3`

etc

If the value of 'i' is different for every banner spot on a particular page, there will be no duplicates. I had a very similar script work in php put I would really love this to work in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you took isn't helping you. I'd suggest you replace your img tags by divs like this in your HTML source:

```
<div class="myImage" id="image1"></div>
<div class="myImage" id="image2"></div>
<div class="myImage" id="image3"></div>
```

Then in your rotate.js file, you could do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Find all images with class myImage
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImage');
    var total  = images.length;

    //Looping through all the elements found
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        //Retrieve array index from the id
        var index = images[i].id.subtring(4);
        //Add the html to the element
        images[i].innerHTML = '<a href="'+link[index]+'"><img src="'+image[index]+'" /></a>';
    }
}
```

The `myImage` class is used to easily retrieve all the divs to be treated and the id is used to know which image to display in the div.

**For the array:**
I would recommend the use of Javascript objects for your banners.
Javascript objects are defined like this: `{}`, they have properties like in the example below:

```
var banners = array();

//Image and link are properties
//push is the function to add an element to an array without specifying the index
banners.push({image:your_url, link:your_url});
//The first banner can then be accessed 
banners[0];
//To access its image
banners[0].image;
//Or
banners[0]['image'];
```

**Example**

rotate.js file

```
var banners = array(); //The first element pushed in the array is at the index 0
banners.push({link: 'www.audio-philia.co.uk', image: 'hificornershop.co.uk/nodups/audiophilia.gif', alt: 'My Image alt'}); 
//Repeat the push for every images

window.onload = function() {
//Find all images with class myImage
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImage');
var total  = images.length;

//Looping through all the elements found
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (banners.length == 0) {
          break;//No more banners can't display anymore            
    }
    //Retrieve a random banner 
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random()*banners.length));
    //Add the html to the element
    images[i].innerHTML = '<a href="'+banners[rnd].link+'"><img src="'+banners[rnd].image+'" alt="'+banners[rnd].alt+'" /></a>';
    banners.splice(rnd, 1);
}
```

}​

HTML

```
<div class="myImage"></div>
<div class="myImage"></div>
<div class="myImage"></div>
<!-- The script should be just before the end of the body tag if possible -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.hificornershop.co.uk/bannercode/rotate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply:)

Should I keep the arrays as they are and replace the function with the code you have provided?

Sorry I'm very new to this and don't fully understand.

Adam

Comment: Updated my answer with my opinion on the arrays. If you have any questions, feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Thanks:) so the array would go before the function? Sorry to be a pain but would it be possible for you to give me an example of the code so i could get a feel for the format and I can fill in the areas accordingly (my banners/links etc).

the file path would be

www.hificornershop.co.uk/bannercode/rotate.js

an example banner would be

http://www.hificornershop.co.uk/nodups/audiophilia.gif

with link

www.audio-philia.co.uk

Sorry to be such a hassle, this baffles me greatly :p Thanks for all your help!

Comment: ohh thats fantastic:) thankyou so much for your help! Ill try and get it on my site asap:)

Comment: sorry to hassle you again, ive had a play on the working example and its great! I just cant get it to display on my site.

my site has an admin area to enter html to display banners. I cant access the head or body directy:/ This has never been a problem before, various java heads have worked. I ust cant display the images:(

Comment: If you can't put scripts in the head or at the body end, you can put the script from the example in the rotate.js file and add this after your HTML: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hificornershop.co.uk/bannercode/rotate.js"></script>`.

Comment: I think I have already done that. All the code is in rotate.js at the previously mentioned location. Where i paste html i have 

<div class="myImage"></div>
<div class="myImage"></div>

src="http://www.hificornershop.co.uk/bannercode/rotate.js"></script>

Comment: Could you give me the URL to the page to investigate the problem?

Comment: sure, thanks. Its www.hificornershop.co.uk

on the left hand side it says "new listings" in white. The code is just above there. Thats why the text has dropped down from the top of the area

Comment: Using the console in Chrome (F12), I see that there is an interrogation point (?) at the end of the rotate.js file which result in a Javascript error.

Comment: oh myy, never would have spotted that, so so sorry to have wasted your time. Everything is perfect now, thank you so much for all your help:) You've been fantastic

Comment: It's my pleasure to help people that want to learn to code. Just remember to use the console to debug your Javascript, it's really helpful.

Comment: Hi, sorry just a few issues. On alot of my pages the banners refuse to display, they also make some of the google maps disappear. I have put the html code into php's and view the php's through iframes - probably not the best solution. This seems to have solved the viewing issues but it means the various iframes are independent to each other and can sometimes show duplicates. The links also open in the iframe which is a pain! aha Im sure there is a better solution, ive just guessed really. Thanks for any help:)

Comment: It appears its the <script src="bannercode/rotate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> which is giving me the issues. Is there any other way to insert java? thanks again, Adam

Comment: I see you included rotate.js multiple times in your HTML. You need to include it once in the head or at the very bottom of the body. And the reason why the images don't show up on various pages is that the script is not found (404), you should put an absolute link to your file : http://hificornershop.co.uk/bannercode/rotate.js.

Comment: thankyou:) it seemed there was a conflict with another js I had aswel. Deleting that has helped considerably. Is there any way in the rotate.js I can ad tags for seo? and have the link open in a new window? Adam

Comment: For the new window add target="_blank" on the link in rotate.js. For the SEO, what is your goal?

Comment: Where abouts do i add it? I tried adding that in a few places. We are currently having SEO done and we were advised that being able to add tags to the images can help significantly. I was wondering if the array can have three elements, the third being alt tags (i think they are called that)

Comment: By experience I can advise you that you don't need to optimise SEO for the ads as they are generated by Javascript and not seen by any search engines. But it is a good practice to add the alts to your site's images.

Comment: Again thank you so much :D! site looks great now. Would there be any reason the code conflicts with google maps? As soon as I paste in <script src="bannercode/rotate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> all the maps disappear. Not to worry though if its no simple solution

Comment: Hi, just a note, Ive tried setting up rotate2.js for a different size of banners on the same page which works fine but rotate.js banners disappears similar to the google maps. Am i only allowed one js at a time on one page?

Comment: the functions on your body tag initialize() et Gunload() don't exist and are causing javascript errors which can prevent other scripts to run. Also when I go on a manufacturer's page, I don't see rotate.js in the source code

Comment: when just one js is inserted it works fine. Ive temporarily taken it off. Ill put it back on now so you can see. As you will be able to see, now the banners are around the site, google maps has disappeared. Same happens when i create a second rotation script for different banners:/

Comment: I was overriding your onload function. I updated the jsfiddle with a new code that shouldn't overwrite it http://jsfiddle.net/c56V6/13/

Comment: fantastic:) thankyou! Very grateful for all your help. Would highly recommend. I changed the variable names in a second rotation script for a different banner size and it works perfectly

Comment: Hey @nebulousGirl - I implemented this for a friend on a site he heps run and works great in Chrome/FF but breaks in IE9 due to the `Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'`. From reading on SO and the web seems to be an IE specific issue. I'm looking at changing things around but wanted to ping you and get your thoughts on it.

Comment: @valien: I didn't remember that `getElementsByClassName` didn't work in IE. (I guess that's because I use jQuery in my everyday projects instead of plain JavaScript) So, I would recommend using some js framework to help solve those browser specific issues.

Comment: @nebulousGirl Yeah, unfortunately the site this is going on is a really limited canned application. I was surprised this even worked in the first place. I'll look and see if there's something else I can do to fix this. Thanks again!

Comment: @nebulousGirl is there a way to add alt tags to the images?  Somewhere in the push, I'm assuming?

Comment: @JohnManly: I modified my example and added an alt. Hope it's not too late.

Answer (score 2):

you can play with this as a base

```
<script>
        var links = ["http://www.abc.com","http://www.def.com","http://www.ghi.com"];
        var images = ["http://www.abc.com/1.gif","http://www.def.com/2.gif","http://www.ghi.com/3gif"];
        var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
            i++;

        }
        },10000);
        </script>



<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.abc.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.abc.com/1.gif" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, been looking for something like this for two days. Question, how would I modify it to use one link, resorted to repeating the link to url. Also, seems there's a delay before the rotating ads start, how does one control that? Lastly, what tutorials can I use to easily learn javascript/ajax, most of the tutorials online with the exceptions of w3schools are quite difficult for starters.